# Bringing aerial cable into an existing PVC Conduit Body

Tags: conduit, low-voltage

I have an existing exterior conduit entering my house, carrying low voltage (CAT6, Coax) wires from our detached garage to my inside equipment room. I need to bring a new fiber-optic cable (for fiber internet) into the same equipment room in the same location where this conduit terminates. My goal here is to avoid having to drill additional holes in the side of the house to bring the cable inside, and see if I can somehow tap into the existing conduit body on the exterior.

Since the conduit contains existing wires, I can't just replace the conduit body with one that has an extra connector. Is there some type of conduit body extension that would bolt in between the existing body and the lid and provide for another ingress point into the conduit? If so, what is it called?

Inside the house, the conduit goes into a junction box, before continuing through flexible interior conduit to the final destination. Worse case, I could drill the wire through next to the conduit body and I still should be able to get it into the junction box to get into the interior conduit for the final segment.

[image: exterior conduit body][image: exterior conduit body]

Comment: How are you getting the fiber-optic to this location,?  What's preventing you from using the exist box?

Comment: Is this new fiber coming in from an overhead drop?  Does the existing conduit terminate in an enclosure (box, cabinet) within the equipment room, or does it just discharge into the wall cavity or into the room itself using a belled end?

Comment: Yes, conduit body extension rings (with at least one supplier calling them conduit body junction boxes) exist. Don't seem quite as common as the other things that will clog up your search results, but they are out there.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, fiber will come in from an aerial drop from a pole behind the house. My thought is to have it brought aerially up to the house behind that gutter downspout, and then drop down behind the downspout to get to the conduit/area to move inside the house. The other side of that conduit body is a junction box, which then connects to EMT/smurf tube that goes into an OpenHouse 36" Structured wiring enclosure in the equipment room, which is where I want the ONT located.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Any links/part numbers you can share?

Comment: So you are stating that a there is not enough space to pass a ~1/4" fiber-optic cable through the conduit between  between the outside 90 degree box in your picture to the JB box on the other side?

Comment: https://www.econline.com/doc/conduit-body-junction-box-0001 or perhaps you can use a cover plate with conduit port from one of the "universal" conduit bodies: https://www.rexelusa.com/usr/Root-Category/Fittings/Conduit-Bodies/Conduit-Bodies---Aluminum/Conduit-Bodies---Universal/Hubbell-TayMac-UCB0100-Conduit-Body%2C-Type%3A-Universal%2C-Size%3A-1%22/p/1053144

Comment: Ecnerwal- these are what I was leading up to but OP states conduit is full, which I find hard to believe.  I didn't suggest yet, because he never ans my question on why he can't use the existing pass-thru

Comment: @Dan -- what size is the existing ENT, how many cables are in it, and what size are said cables?

Comment: ThreePhase - from my understanding these are communication lines only, no power.  The fibre optic has no power in them.  There is no space-heat limit requirements.  If 120v were in the conduit, it would already be a code violation.

Comment: @Programmer66 Sorry if I was unclear, there *is* space in the conduit for the cable. By   "full", I meant "containing", not that there was no space for additional cable. I just don't know how to cleanly get it *into* the conduit body on the outside since it's essentially sealed (aside from the lid). I suppose I could just drill into the side of it, but not sure if that's a good idea?

Comment: @Programmer66 -- there are still *physical* fill limits so that pulling tensions don't become excessive

Comment: Ecnerwal has provided the ans to your question- Use the expansion or addition port cover in lieu of the original cover.  Add a bottom loop to the cable before going into the box shown.  The real issue you face is that the fibre cable has specific bend radius so you have to make sure is not exceeded in the entry to the house, and in the jb on the other side.  On the other side (interior), the fibre could just be run on the surface to your rack and NOT run through the EMT conduit with the other com cables.

Comment: Most modern drop cable uses Reduced Bend Radius fiber (which is a remarkably small upcharge when buying the cable) to make installing it into houses practical. Do, of course, check what the minimum bend radius is (ask the provider.)

Comment: @Programmer66 Thanks, but I can't seem to find one that will work with my conduit body. Any links? I have a Cantex 2" LB PVC Conduit body. The Hubbell ones linked above only go up to 1" so the covers are smaller and don't fit the Cantex opening. On the inside, the room it enters is different from the equipment room, which is why it needs to go through the interior ENT to get to the right place. Worst case, if the bends don't work, we can run it on the exterior surface of the house to the proper location to come into the bay with the wiring enclosure. Just trying to avoid extra holes if I can.

Comment: Have to let the electricians answer where to find an expansion cover that large.  For pulling the fiber that a different question with  too many variables on the inside JB and EMT size, and proper fiber cable pulling with a multiple 90 degree bends. You hit on what I was thinking, just enter the house in the equipment room with a plain bushing and it would be the provider's job to install and bring it into the house.

Comment: @Dan -- is the interior conduit 2" as well? Or does it step down in size at the JB where it turns to run from the penetration to the equipment room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** I wasn't able to achieve the install without another hole, but it all worked out cleanly in the end.

Thanks to all who commented on this, your insight was helpful as I thought through how to do this. Ultimately, I wasn't able to find an actual port cover or extension ring anywhere -- seems like a potential business opportunity, but maybe this is a rare scenario :)

Today was install day, and ultimately it was quite successful. Since a slackbox was required to hold the excess fiber, and combine the outdoor and indoor cables, the tech drilled a 1/4" hole through the back of the interior junction box to exit the house to the right of the conduit body. The fiber enters the back of the slackbox and it's a nice clean look. It's sealed up with silicone, and just needs a coat of paint to make it blend in to the house. The aerial fiber comes from the pole and down behind the downspout.

[image: exterior fiber slackbox]

On the inside, we attached pull string to one coax line in the wiring cabinet and pulled it into the junction box. Then, we attached the fiber to the coax (along with another pull string for the future), and re-pulled it back to the destination. It's basically a straight run along an interior wall, and worked out great. The ENT is 1.5" diameter, I believe, to answer a prior comment. It's got a bunch of wires in there, but there was plenty of room for the fiber. And yes, the interior cable they used is pretty bendable, so had no issues in that regard.

[image: interior junction box]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your own question! Please be sure to select it as the "correct" answer, too. That looks like a very nice, neat, tidy installation both inside and outside.